# Media query not working at 798px BUT will work on 1786px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

Okay I have what seems to be a simple problem. I have a media query that changes the nav from burger to expanded version in 768px. However it doesn't work.

**As in: it should apply burger nav when it is less then 768px and then expand accordingly.**

Any ideas what is happening, I THINK its a small mistake I can't seem to catch

```js
/* NAVIGATION ON CLICK */

// Primary menu drop down (mobile)
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});


/* NAVIGATION ON HOVER */
// Sub menu drop down 
$(".main-navigation ul li.menu-item-has-children").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".sub-menu:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

$(".primary-toggle").click(function() {
  $(" .main-navigation ul:first").toggleClass("toggle-on");
});

// $(".main-navigation li.menu-item-has-children").mouseleave(function() {
//   $(".sub-menu").removeClass("toggle-on");
// });
```

```css
/* 
 # HEADER
 */

*,
html {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.site-header {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Burger Nav Styling */

#sidebar-btn {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 40px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

#sidebar-btn span {
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 75%;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Main Menu */

.main-navigation {
  padding: 2rem;
}


/*.main-navigation .menu {
 display: none;
 padding: 1rem;

 } */

.menu-test-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 264px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-navigation .menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  min-width: 80px;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;*/
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main-navigation ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* SUB Menu styles */

.sub-menu.toggle-on {
  display: block;
}

.main-navigation ul,
.main-navigation ul ul,
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}


/* Positioning x y of EACH sub menus */

.main-navigation ul ul {
  background-color: pink;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: 150px;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: green;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: black;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
}

.main-navigation ul ul ul ul ul ul {
  background-color: silver;
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
}


/* TABLET MENU */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  .primary-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-navigation ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .menu-test-container {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
  <div class="site-branding">
    <div class="site-branding-text">
      <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">LOGO</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
    <button class="primary-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
    <div id="sidebar-btn">
     <span></span>
     <span></span>
     <span></span>    
    </div>   
   </button>
    <div class="menu-test-container">
      <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu" aria-expanded="true">
        <li id="menu-item-2035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2035">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Services</a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
      </button>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2076" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2076">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Commercial</a>
              <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol">-</span>
        </button>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-2082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2082">
                  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Rural</a>
                  <button class="dropdown-toggle toggled-on" aria-expanded="true">
           <span class="dropdown-symbol">-</span>
          </button>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="menu-item-2081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2081">
                      <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/services/">Electrical</a>
                      <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
             <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
            </button>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-2079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2079">
                          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Residential</a>
                          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
              </button>
                          <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-2083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2083"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2084">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/asd/">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2045">
          <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a>
          <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
      </button>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-2078">
              <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">About</a>
              <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span>
        </button>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-2099" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2099">
                  <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/news-updates/">News Updates</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- #site-navigation -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</header>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}` the basic tablet media querie for `Portrait and Landscape`

Comment: But i don't understand why the simple @media screen and (min-width:768px) not working?

Comment: @Shaz ensure that, your browser zoom setting is setted on 100%....!

Comment: try using it as `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)` , better syntax, but it should work, maybe you are on a mac computer or laptop?

Answer (score 2):

**Okay, I figured it out. Thought I'll post it here so I can close the question.**

**Answer:** View port tag missing! Make sure you have the following in the html head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: oops , forgot you had to add that one. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 0):

@Shaz if you want to change your menu in smaller screens you should change your media query to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 /*
   Code Here
 */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 /*
   Code Here
 */
}
```

Comment: Tablet has a max width of 1024px??

Answer (score 0):

What you have doe is right. just replace min-width with max-width.

for more details refer: [here](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width)

use min-width when writing media queries from mobile to desktop screens.
use max-width when writing media queries from desktop to mobile screens.